# Modifying filled area in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've an interactive figure on which plot is drawn incrementally, one chunk at time.

That is, in a loop I get some sampling data, then I add them to existing curves in the plot and redraw the picture. For this, I'm using get/set_x/ydata functions. Something on this line:

```
# Get initial data
time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
samples = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
c = plot_curve(time, samples)
# Get new data
time2 = [6, 7, 8]
samp2 = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
c.set_xdata(append(c.get_xdata(), time2))
c.set_ydata(append(c.get_ydata(), samp2))
```

Problem is, I'm also filling some area near the curve (e.g. the space between the curve and the x axis), using fill_between. Currently, I'm creating lots of small chunks in this way:

```
# Filling initial chunk
fill_between(time, samples, [0 for i in time])
# Filling next chunk
fill_between(time[-1] + time2, samples[-1] + samp2, [0 for i in time2] + [0])
```

(I know this code stinks, but it's for giving an idea).

So, problem is: there is one curve, but filled areas are 2 (one for each data chunk).
This creates small artifacts in the drawing, because each filled area is very near to the next one, with a very little space among them.

Is there a way to do this kind of incremental work also on the filling area?

For example, could be nice to keep 2 curves (one equal to c.get_ydata() and one of zeros) and having matplotlib to automatically fill the area between them, without having to call the command explicitly - so that the filled area would always be up-to-date with the sampling points.

Or, another nice way, would be to represent the filled area using the sampling points, instead of a polygon, so that I could update the area with method similar to get/set_x/ydata.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: I suggest sending an email to the mailing list or create and issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less hackish way to do this is to do

```
pc = fill_between(time, samples)
```

(note that the default is y2 = 0, so you don't need that list comprehension)

Then, when you update your figure

```
time2 = [6, 7, 8]
samp2 = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8]
time_update = append(c.get_xdata(), time2)
samp_update = append(c.get_ydata(), samp2)
c.set_xdata(time_update)
c.set_ydata(samp_update)
pc.remove()
pc = fill_between(time_update, samp_update)
```

Instead of making a new smaller region every time, just wipe out the old one and fully re-create it for all of the data.  No idea how this will affect your speed, but I would be suprised if it is slower than what you are doing now.

Comment: Well, I didn't try a performance comparison, but you should know that sampling points can be in high number, like million (>1, <100), and update frequency can be relatively high (once every 1000 samples or less).

Comment: @AkiRoss Is the data pretty smooth?  You might be able to get away with aggressively down-sampling before calling `fill_between` (as you only have ~1k pixel across on your monitor, it is being down sample anyway)

Comment: Unluckly I've already considered that option... Data is not smooth at all. Consider that the plot is saved in a vectorial format allowing a representation wider than the monitor.